# How to delete "undeletable" lines in Vi?

Tags: grep, data-recovery, vi

**Background**

I accidentally deleted an important python script, and so I ran the command

```
sudo grep --binary-files=text --context=100 'unique string' /dev/sda1 > recover_file
```

to search for it on my hard drive and save matches to `./recover_file`. When I open `./recover_file` in Vi ("Vi Unimproved", not Vim) I see that it is ~10800 lines long and contains many versions of my ~200 line file, with some junk between each occurrence, as expected. But there are also hundreds of strange lines with unexpected behavior that I will attempt to describe.

I have line numbers on. If line 19 is the first strange line in the file, upon opening the file I get a message a the bottom of the window saying

```
Conversion error on line 19
```

Initially the strange lines appear as empty lines, like the lines displayed at the bottom of a document when there are no more lines in the file to be displayed, with a `~` character at the far left edge of the window, but located between two other lines, not at the end of the file:

```
    18 junk junk junk
~
    20 junk junk junk
```

When I attempt to delete line 19 using `dd`, nothing happens. If I delete a normal line, then line 19's appearance changes and it looks like any other blank line:

```
    18 junk junk junk
    19
    20 junk junk junk
```

But as soon as I move my cursor over it, the line number disappears and it looks just like it did before. If I try to perform any operation on it, such as inserting or appending text, I get

```
Error: unable to retrieve line 19
```

If I write the file to the disk, I get

```
Error: recover_file: Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character.
recover_file: WARNING: FILE TRUNCATED.
```

Then, if I close and re-open the file, I see that all lines from 19 onward have been removed, leaving only lines 1-18. I was able to reproduce the situation and copy a recent version of the python file into a new file, after which further digging in `./recover_file` produced a segmentation fault and the entire file was lost.

**Questions**

1) For future reference, is there a way I can remove these strange lines so that I can save the file directly without losing important data, or will I always need to highlight and copy from the terminal window?

2) I assume that this behavior is due to the presence of binary code in `./recover_file` not corresponding to text characters, which Vi cannot render. If someone could confirm/correct this impression and perhaps provide further explanation, I would be grateful.

**Update**

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I'm running lubuntu 18.04 as a virtual machine on VMware Workstation 14 Player.

Comment: I would have added `| strings` at the end of the command, before redirecting to get rid of junk chars. Nonethess, with your commands, you can also get extraneous EOF chars, I think.

Comment: ... or if applicable use `extundelete` as described here [Accidentally deleted a folder](https://askubuntu.com/a/150673/178692)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro putting `| strings` after the `grep` command and before the redirect `>` worked pretty well. If you want to post it as an answer I'll select it. If not, I'll post it in a day or two.

Comment: I will post it and explain why it works in a couple of hours, preparing to go to work now.

Comment: If `/dev/sda1` was the disk that contains the filesystem where you wrote `recover_file` you could easily have overwritten your deleted data with your "recovering" data. This still might be case. This isn't a good way to recover a lost file - but good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at your script, you are dumping and try to edit, searching and line editing, binary files with the `vi` text editor.

In that way, you will encounter a lot of control characters that will subvert the notion of lines, length of lines and in some stituations, even possibly the end-of-file.

Since you are only interested in text, and you are already somewhat parsing the disk contents, I would add a `strings` command to it to discard non-text characters.

To be able to handle your output in vi, you may thus change your script to:

```
sudo grep --binary-files=text --context=100 'unique string' /dev/sda1 | strings > recover_file
```

I also suspect it will be more efficient to discard those control chars to begin with as in:

```
sudo strings /dev/sda1 | grep --context=100 'unique string' > recover_file
```

Though I am not entirely sure this last instruction with give the same results due to being handled as text and not binary.

From `man strings`

> strings - print the strings of printable characters in files.
>
> Description
>
> For each file given, GNU strings prints the printable character
>   sequences that are at least 4 characters long (or the number given
>   with the options below) and are followed by an unprintable character.
>   By default, it only prints the strings from the initialized and loaded
>   sections of object files; for other types of files, it prints the
>   strings from the whole file.